# Default File Manager in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: files, dolphin

I have just changed from using Kubuntu to Ubuntu with the cinnamon branding.

I was wondering what the default File Manager in Ubuntu 17.10 is called as I wish to download Insync to sync my 3 google drives. Isnsyn asks for name of default FM

Also, could I change back to Dolphin as default manager or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default file manager in Ubuntu is Nautilus.

And yes, you can install dolphin in Ubuntu. As you can install any Kubuntu software in Ubuntu by installing the package as you would with any other piece of software.

Good idea? Not really. Since you will be mixing 2 operating systems there is a lot of overhead (libraries that do the same for a specific program are installed twice for each operating system).

Installing dolphin from the software center:

[image]

and you can also tick the "add-ons" if you want.